# Laravel sort by related table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a little complicated relationship and I also want to order my results using column in the other table, let's see:

```
$book = Book::where('id', '=', $id)->with([
        'versions.titles' => function ($query) {

            //I want to paginate table "titles" 
            $query->groupBy('titles.title')->paginate(15);
        },
        'versions.titles.numbers' => function ($query) {

            // but I want to order it by "numbers.order_key"
            $query->orderBy('numbers.order_key', 'asc')->get();
        }])
        ->first();
```

Of course, this code doesn't work properly - `titles` column isn't sorted by `numbers.order_key`. Does anybody have any idea how to get it? I don't really want to use joins because of a complication of my relationships.

### Update:

My models

Book:
-id

Title:
-id

Version:
-id
-book_id

titles_version:
-title_id
-version_id

Number:
-id
-book_id
-title_id

I want to obtain one nested record to paginate titles, e.g. `$book->versions->titles->paginate(15)`, where titles have to be ordered by `numbers.order_key`.

Comment: What do you expect as a result, `Book` object with `version` property? With `version` object with propery `titles` - an array of titles (strings?). What objects do you have? Book -> Version -> Title -> Number and every `->` is `hasMany`?

Comment: I updated my question. I want to obtain object `Book` with `versions` and `titles` and `numbers`.